# PHP Soap Request works in SoapUI but not in PHP

Tags: php, soap, interface

I have to perform a lot of SOAP requests. So I built a request in SoapUI which works perfectly fine. I hit the play button and get the expected result.

Now I want to create the same SOAP request using PHP, but this doesn't work.
The "connection" to the WDSL file works. When I do `__getFunctions` or `__getTypes` it works as expected.

PHP-Code:

```
$wdsl = "http://MYSERVER/v2?wsdl";        
$soap = new SoapClient($wdsl, array('soap_version'=>SOAP_1_2,"trace"=>1,'encoding' => 'UTF-8');
try {
    $x =$soap->getHotelProduct($req);
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
var_dump($x);
```

$req is the (in SoapUI) working Request.

The error I get when I perform the Script is:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (2) { ["Error"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (2) { ["_"]=> string(40) "The request contains an unknown AuthKey." ["Code"]=> int(1) } ["Success"]=> bool(false) }
```

But: The AuthKey is absolutly correct! I even copy&pasted it from SoapUI where it works.

Hope anybody out here can help me.

Answer (score 0):

please try the following. Try using __soapCall();

```
try
{       
   $x =$soap->__soapCall("getHotelProduct",array($req));
   $x = (array) $x;      //convert to array
}
// ..... //

var_dump($x);
```

Comment: Hello & thank you very much. This also does not work. array(2) { ["Error"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (2) { ["_"]=> string(40) "The request contains an unknown AuthKey." ["Code"]=> int(1) } ["Success"]=> bool(false) }